# Limiting permissions for aws sqs:ListQueues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs

Is it possible to limit the permissions to the amount of queues that a function can pull when using boto3 to list sqs queues?

I'm currently using boto3 to pull a list of queues according to a prefix:

```
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
response = sqs.list_queues(
   QueueNamePrefix = 'some-prefix'
)
```

I'm only able to make this work w/ the following policy:

```
{
   "Action": "sqs:ListQueues",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Resource": "*"
}
```

editing this to limit the resource like so:

```
{
   "Action": "sqs:ListQueues",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Resource": "some-prefix*"
}
```

or using a condition:

```
{
   "Action": "sqs:ListQueues",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Resource": "*",
   "Condition": {"StringLike":{"aws:SourceArn": "some-prefix*"}}
}
```

gets me an AccesDenied.

In the [API policy documentation for sqs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-api-permissions-reference.html) the ListQueues permission resource is stated as `arn:aws:sqs:region:account_id:*`. I'm wondering if there's any way to limit the permission so that my python function would not have the ability to get access to list all queues in sqs.

Comment: [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsqs.html) is right doc you should be looking at. Notice for `ListQueues` action, there is no condition keys available, which means `"*"` is the only one that will work.

Comment: @jellycsc i think both of our links say the same thing. my question was whether there's any method to getting around this on the security side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon SQS - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsqs.html), the `ListQueues` API call does not accept any `Condition` options.

However, it does accept a `QueueNamePrefix`: *"A string to use for filtering the list results. Only those queues whose name begins with the specified string are returned."*

Therefore, you can limit the queues by specifying your prefix in that field, rather than using a Condition.